# Flutter- call function after function

Tags: flutter

I want to call function2 after function1 finished. 
To do that I did like that.

this is function 1.

```
  Future _uploadImages() async {
    setState(() {isUploading = true;});

    images.forEach((image) async {

      await image.requestThumbnail(300, 300).then((_) async {
        final int date = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        final String storageId = '$date$uid';

      final StorageReference ref =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images').child(storageId);

        final file = image.thumbData.buffer.asUint8List();

       StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);

      Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;

      final String url = downloadUrl.toString();

      imageUrls.add(url);

      });

     });

  }
```

this is function 2

```
    Future _writeImageInfo() async {
    await _uploadImages().then((_) async {
     await Firestore.instance.collection('post').document(uid).setData({
        'imageUrls': imageUrls,
      }).then((_) { 
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
       });

  }
```

But console says function2's imageUrls called when list length = 0 because it's called before function 1 finished.
I don't know why that function not called after function 1.
How can I make this right?

Comment: Check this may help you https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-functions-that-return-futures

Comment: Thank you for the comment and I did what the document says but still call when list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of your `images.forEach`. The `.forEach` doesn't work with async callback. Therefore it doesn't wait the end of each the foreach to continue the function.

In general, don't use `.forEach` in dart anyway. Dart did a great job on the `for` keyword directly.

So ultimately, you should do the following:

```
for (final image in images) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you I won't use forEach anymore. Now it complains this `[dart] The type 'List<Asset>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Stream.` do you know what's happening?

Comment: My bad my bad, the `await for` wasn't needed. A simple `for` was enough. Fixed